# why did this happen when objective-c has conflict return type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, crash, return

Here is the problem: I want to show sequenced diagrams on iOS device like gif effect, and I use UIImageView animation feature, so implement a method at below:

```
// Animation.m
// @files:     diagrams' array
// @fileDir:   file directory
// @imageview: Just UIImageView
//
- (void)showSeqDiagram:(NSArray*)files
            fileDirect:(NSString*)fileDir
             imageView:(UIImageView*)imageview
{
    int cnt = [files count];
    NSMutableArray * images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:cnt];
    for (id file in files)
    {
        NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", fileDir, file];
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        if(!image)
            continue;
        [images addObject:image];
    }
    imageview.animationImages = images;

    imageview.animationDuration = 5;
    imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageview startAnimating];
}
```

Up to this, things went well. I made a mistake about declaration of ***return type*** in header file like this:

```
//Animation.h
- (UIImageView*)showSeqDiagram:(NSArray*)files
                    fileDirect:(NSString*)fileDir
                     imageView:(UIImageView*)imageview;
```

and I call this method in - (void)loadView

```
- (void)loadview
{
......
[self showSeqDiagram:files fileDirect:fileDir imageView:imageview];
......
}
```

then crashed at calling position and throw EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, ) on iPhone5 simulator and device, iOS verison9.3;

occasionally crashed on iPhone6 simulator, iOS version9.3;

never crashed on iPhone6/6plus device and iPhone6plus simulator, tested on iOS 7-9.

I know it's wrong, but want to know why this happend, could anybody give a explanation? thanks in advance~

Comment: Where did you take the imageView, is it in story board/Xib or programmatically?

Comment: Modify the return type in order that in .h and .m it's the same method. Try to set breakpoint to find out where exactly is the issue on that method (line) or if it's because the method declaration doesn't match its implementation.

Comment: u can try to delcare different return value in *.h and *.m, compiler just throw a warning, and it also could be called in other files and they match indeed. try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, My co-worker of mine had answer, here are the details:

- Firstly 2 Background:
- arm-arch store method return value in %rax register;
- and object won't release immediately in ARC mode and
  _obj_release_XXX has the **lowest priority** in RunLoop;

so showSeqDiagram won't return any value, so %rax register has no value, but autoReleasePool try to release "UIImageView" obj in %rax after a short time(**priority is the lowest**). In such short time, if some other method in other RunLoop over-write %rax, then it won't crash; otherwise, if nobody re-write %rax, then crash happened.

this could partly explain why crashed randomly. Are there any better answers?